# Easy way to build objects for target and x86 at the same time

Tags: build, compilation, makefile, cross-compiling

Currently, this is how I build my object files for my  x86 compiler.

```
CC=g++
%.o: %.cpp
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) $(LIBPATH) -DPC -c $^ -o $@
```

How can I easily switch between g++ and my cross compiler? How can I compile both x86 and binaries for my target at the same time? I seem to be limited to compiling with only one compiler right now. Is there a way to come about this without having to list all my object files one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the tool chain while giving make

Just an extra variable `CROSS_COMPILE` would do that

The makefile would rather look like this

```
CROSS_COMPILE :=

CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)g++


%.o: %.cpp

     $(CC) $(CFLAGS)$(INCPATH) $(LIBPATH) -DPC -c $^ -o $@
```

So if u just give `make` then `CC` is used as `g++` and get compiled for x86, if you give `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` then it would be compiled for `ARM`

You can use whatever the tool chain you want the concept remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Sagar's answer does address how to switch between compilers, but does not address how to both do that and the main part of the question, which is how to do both targets at the same time.

To do both targets at the same time, you probably want to separate the objects into directories related to the compiler or target used,  and then based on the directory of object, figure out what compiler to use.

So, something like below, in the simplest case, where the sources are in current directory, and the directory is the same as the compiler name.  Fill in the user-defined COMPILER function with how you like to calculate your compiler name, based on the directory of the object file, which is the argument $1 to the function.

```
define COMPILER
$1
endef

.PRECIOUS: %/.
%/.:
        mkdir -p $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.o: $$(notdir $$*.cpp) | $$(@D)/.
        $(call COMPILER, $(@D)) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: What is the proper syntax to have .SECONDEXPANSION as a dependency?
would it be target: .SECONDEXPANSION?

Comment: @Olihoops it's not a dependency, it is just a built-in keyword, check the manual, it is needed so I can calculate $$ here